# QuickContactBadge setImageBitmap get gray background

Tags: android, quickcontactbadge

Salam
I have a `ListView` in each row have a `QuickContactBadge` image, after i `setImageBitmap` , the background of badge image get gray or black and some times corner of images get small and rounded.
any suggestion ?

```
                try {
                if (BOX.getPNs().size() == 1) {
                    if (QCH.getName() == null) {
                        holder.Badge.setImageBitmap(null);
                        holder.Badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.unknown);
                    } else {
                        if (QCH.holder.tId == null || QCH.holder.tId == 0) {
                            holder.Badge.setImageBitmap(null);
                            holder.Badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.personal);
                        } else {
                            holder.Badge.setImageResource(0);
                            holder.Badge.setImageBitmap(QCH.getThumbnail());
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    holder.Badge.setImageBitmap(null);
                    holder.Badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.multiplus);
                }
                holder.Badge.assignContactUri(QCH.getContactUri());
                holder.Badge.setMode(ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_SMALL);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

sory for the poor quality image
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to provide use with some screenshots?

Comment: If you do not set the background bitmap everything works fine I assume

Comment: You mean in code or default value؟

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was Badge.assignContactUri(); , when i replace it my little problem was solved